# Call on members-loop with AJAX in buddypress(Wordpress)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, buddypress

I’m creating a (Buddypress/Wordpress) page where I want to list all members and then let the visitors filter them by for example location by checking checkboxes.
I created a quick mockup in photoshop of what I’m creating.

[image]

I have modified the PHP file *members-loop.php* to do what I want, and my script successfully works and only list users with locations I add to my `$selectedLocations` array. I want visitors to be able to add locations to this arrays with checkboxes.
When a user checks a box I want the page to reload the *member-loop.php* so that I can add a `[POST]` to the submit and filter the page with the criteria from the checkbox. My problem is that I have no idea how to call the loop again.  Right now I'm just trying to reload the loop, and I'll add the `POST` when I have achieved that. 
I'm trying to call on the loop with this function:

```
function vedCheckboxValg(){
          $.ajax({
              url:ajaxurl,
              type:'GET',
            data: {
                action: 'members'
              },
              success: function(members){
                  alert('funka det?');
              $('#phpdiv').append(members);  

              }

        });

}
```

The script itself works If I call on a PHP file on my root with a simple `echo`, but whatever I do to call on *members-loop* is not working, and just returns `0`.